# How to increase project limits in Memgrpah Cloud?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm using Memgraph Cloud (paid version, not free trial.). In the pricing page I can see the text that I should be able to create "unlimited number of projects" but when I try to create 4th, I get error "maximum 3 projects allowed".

What is the cause for this message?

Comment: Hi, it's could be due to a configuration issue or a limitation set by the Memgraph Cloud platform... did you contact Memgraph support for assistance?

Comment: Hi Yoshua! I've done that now and now I have larger limit :) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an initial limitation of 3 just for the sake of a user and the charges that might apply unintentionally; more like a safe limit. If you need more projects [you need to contact support and ask](https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/memgraph-cloud#create-a-new-memgraph-cloud-project) them for increased number of projects.